# relations in (\mathbb P^1)^n

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

What is a minimal set of relations of the image of $(\mathbb P^1)^n$ in the Segre embedding? For $n=2$ its just the determinant $x_1x_2.y_1y_2=x_1y_2.x_2y_1$. Is it written explicitly somewhere?

Comment: Yes, see p. 2 of [this paper](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~asnowden/papers/segre-062011.pdf).